# Finding what type of class

Tags: java

I have three class  ClassA , ClassB, ClassC. All the three classes implements "ClassInterface" interface .

```
class ClassA<T> implements ClassInterface<T>{}

class ClassB<T> implements ClassInterface<T>{}

class ClassC<T> implements ClassInterface<T>{}
```

I have method in other class ClassD:

```
void methodname(ClassInterface<T> CI[]){}
```

in the method I need to find to which class each element belong to ? i.e whether CI[i] belong to ClassA, ClassB or ClassC?

I tried "instacneof" but it giving me errors. I don't know whether  my approach is correct or not

Comment: Agree with Mitch about it being a bad design idea. But `instanceof` should have worked. What error did you get?

Comment: "instacneof" almost sounds like a pimple treatment. Are you sure you spelt it correctly in your code?

Answer (score 7):

That would be a bad design idea! You are essentially 'up-casting'. The whole point of passing a parameter as an interface is that the called method should not know or care what the implementing class is.

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes the whole point of polymorphism seems to pass some people by :-)

Answer (score 4):

Switch your point of view, instead that trying to understand the type from a caller method, give every class a different implementation and let every of them have a specialized behaviour.

This means implementing a common method declared by interface in ClassA, ClassB and ClassC and invoke it from the caller.

Answer (score 2):

make sure you aren't trying to template your instanceof checks...  Template parameters are "erased" during compilation so you don't have access them for instanceof and other run-time checks.

But yes, what you are doing is generally indicative of bad design.

Answer (score 2):

Generics are implemented using Type Erasure, which means that `ClassInterface<String>` and `ClassInterface<Double>` are both just plain-old raw `ClassInterface` at runtime.

Hence, there something like this would be meaningless:

```
if(x instanceof ClassInterface<String>) {
  // ... do something
} else if (x instanceof ClassInterface<Double>) {
  // ... do something else
}
```

because at runtime all the bytecode would say is

```
if(x instanceof ClassInterface) {
  // ... do something
} else if (x instanceof ClassInterface) {
  // ... do something else
}
```

As other posters have mentioned, this sort of casting is a code smell that's indicative of a poor design.  If you have to do some handling based on which implementation of `ClassInterface` you have, then depending on your situation you should consider:

- Defining a method on the interface and doing your specific implementations on each subclass
- Applying the [Visitor Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) to your interface and implementations so that you can write a visitor that does the custom handling logic by item wherever you need it
- If you really want the type-casting like behavior, then you can use the [Super Type Token](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) pattern to make decisions based on the type parameter.  This could be something as simple as adding a method to your interface like: `Class<T> getType();` then doing an if statement like:

```
// I really wouldn't recommend this, but it still is an option...
if(String.class.equals(x.getType())) {
  // ... do something
} else if (Double.class.equals(x.getType())) {
  // ... do something else
}
```